# How do I modify part of index name in python/pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to change a portion in the index of this practice dataset from the word `"low"` to `"down"`.

I tried searching for some solutions, but it was mainly renaming the entire index. I'm just trying to rename a small section of it.

```
                         NUM          Npc      Value    
OOF_Mic.Y9_low_of_XX    +0.4206969    Nil     0.000666  
OOF_Mic.Y5_low_of_XX    +0.4206969    Nil     0.000666  
OOF_Mic.Y7_low_of_XX    +0.4206969    Nil     0.000666
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call your index by using `DataFrame.index`, and we can use `str.replace` to replace your `low` part for `down`:

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace('low', 'down')

print(df)
                            NUM  Npc     Value
idx                                           
OOF_Mic.Y9_down_of_XX  0.420697  Nil  0.000666
OOF_Mic.Y5_down_of_XX  0.420697  Nil  0.000666
OOF_Mic.Y7_down_of_XX  0.420697  Nil  0.000666
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.index = df.index.str.replace('_low_', '_down_')
```

if you are certain that `low` never appears anywhere else, than skip `_` in both.

Answer (score 0):

I found two ways:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str).str.replace('low', 'down')
df

    NUM Npc Value
OOF_Mic.Y9_down_of_XX   0.420697    Nil 0.000666
OOF_Mic.Y5_down_of_XX   0.420697    Nil 0.000666
OOF_Mic.Y7_down_of_XX   0.420697    Nil 0.000666
```

or:

```
df1 = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'temp'})
df1.loc[:,'temp'] = df1.temp.astype(str).str.replace('low', 'down')
df1.set_index('temp')

NUM Npc Value
temp            
OOF_Mic.Y9_down_of_XX   0.420697    Nil 0.000666
OOF_Mic.Y5_down_of_XX   0.420697    Nil 0.000666
OOF_Mic.Y7_down_of_XX   0.420697    Nil 0.000666
```